# Make error with g95: Could not determine flag to name executables

Tags: fortran, g95

I am trying to build [EXCiT!NG](https://github.com/exciting/exciting) with the g95 compiler. It seams to work until this errors appear:

```
checking for linker flag to name executables... configure: error: Could not determine flag to name executables
See `config.log' for more details.
../Make.common:107: die Regel für Ziel „lib/libFoX_common.a“ scheiterte
make[2]: *** [lib/libFoX_common.a] Fehler 1
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/robin/Dokumente/exciting/build/serial“ wird verlassen
Makefile:3: die Regel für Ziel „all“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [all] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/robin/Dokumente/exciting/build/serial“ wird verlassen
Makefile:14: die Regel für Ziel „serial“ scheiterte
make: *** [serial] Fehler 2
```

Comment: Please check I linked the correct project. Please also note that g95 has been unmaintained for a long time and is not well supported by build script makers and programmers of Fortran projects in general.

Comment: The information we need to help you is likely, as the output states, in the file `config.log`.

Comment: I have the same problem with gfortran:

Comment: xsltproc ../../xml/schema/schemaexpand.xsl ../../xml/schema/input.xsd > ../../xml/excitinginput.xsd
/bin/sh: 1: xsltproc: not found
../Make.common:148: die Regel für Ziel „../../xml/excitinginput.xsd“ scheiterte
make[2]: *** [../../xml/excitinginput.xsd] Fehler 127
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/robin/Dokumente/exciting/build/serial“ wird verlassen
Makefile:3: die Regel für Ziel „all“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [all] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/robin/Dokumente/exciting/build/serial“ wird verlassen
Makefile:23: die Regel für Ziel „serial“ scheiterte
make: *** [serial] Fehler 2

Comment: I tried it with two different compilers (g95 and gfortran) and two versions of exciting. It it doesn't compile properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem you have been seeing and was able to successfully compile EXCiT!NG.  The big hint was in your comment which mentioned the `xsltproc` error.  Note that the error message says: `xsltproc: not found`, which means that the command itself is missing and the relevant package needs to be installed; also, one has to be careful to ensure the project is completely "clean" before trying to recompile again.

The following procedure was carried out on a Debian (stretch) system, hence you will need to replace the package installation commands with the appropriate ones for your system.

### Prerequisite installation

First, ensure that the required packages exist:

```
sudo apt install build-essential make gfortran xsltproc git
```

The `build-essential` package is required so that the standard C-compilers and libraries are available.  `make` is necessary in order to build the package (as mentioned in the [EXCiT!NG README](https://github.com/exciting/exciting/blob/master/README)), and it seems that only `gfortran` is available on Debian systems and hence I haven't tested the setup with `g95`.  The `xsltproc` package provides the `xsltproc` command so that the XML libraries (FoX XML) can be compiled; note that this might have been the problem in the error you mention initially, because you got error output such as:

```
../Make.common:107: die Regel für Ziel „lib/libFoX_common.a“ scheiterte
```

The `git` package is required so that the source code could be checked out from GitHub.

### Cloning and building the project

After cloning the source code and entering the project directory

```
git clone git@github.com:exciting/exciting.git
cd exciting/
```

It was merely a matter of running

```
make
```

and selecting the `gfortran` option at the menu and then to answer "no" to the questions about MPI and SMP, which seemed to be the recommended default answer.  Also, I noticed that your error output mentioned the "serial" `make` target

```
Makefile:14: die Regel für Ziel „serial“ scheiterte
```

hence I assume that these are also the settings that you are using.

After that, `make` completed successfully.  Running the test suite via

```
make test
```

unfortunately didn't pass, however the errors seem to be due to truncated lines, e.g.

```
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
../../src/src_eigensystem/hmlint.f90:296:132: haaij(if1,if3,ias)=zsum+t1*apwfr(nrmt(is),1,io1,l1,ias)*apwdfr(io2,l1,ias)*1d0/(1d0-veffmt(1,nrmt(is),ias)*y00*a)
```

which might be a `gfortran` problem, however it's difficult to say.  It could be the case that the software does work as expected; this is something you will have to test by comparing the program's output with a known DFT system.

### Reduce potential errors with a clean project directory

Note that cleaning the project after a failed build with

```
make clean
```

and rebuilding didn't seem to want to build the project successfully.  I had to revert to deleting the project completely and re-cloning from GitHub.

Comment: The truncation error means that the code is written with longer lines than the Fortran standard permts and needs a special flag to allow longer lines.

Comment: Yes, that's what I guessed when I saw it; however, I didn't want to start changing the application code around too much in order to solve the problem.